# Copying from current buffer then creating a file and pasting to it in background

Tags: neovim

There are sometimes when I am trying to copy to my current buffer (y) and pasting to a different buffer(p) however, sometimes I will fat-finger it and press maybe one or more other keys when trying to paste to a different buffer and as a result the following happens:

1. a new document is created(with some symbol maybe a `/` or `.` or something)
2. the contents in the current buffer are then populated in that newly created file

I know that `%` will create a new file

This action is happening in the background because I don't know this is happening until I go to commit my files and all of a sudden I will see a filename that I've never seen in the project or just a strange series of symbols. here are my remappings

```lua
vim.g.mapleader=";"

vim.keymap.set("v", "K", ":m '<-2<CR>gv=gv")
vim.keymap.set("v", "J", ":m '>+1<CR>gv=gv")

vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>pv", vim.cmd.Ex)
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-J>", "<C-W><C-J>")
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-h>", "<C-W><C-H>")
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-K>", "<C-W><C-K>")
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-L>", "<C-W><C-L>")
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>Y", [["+Y]])
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>s", [[:%s/\<<C-r><C-w>\>/<C-r><C-w>/gI<Left><Left><Left>]])
vim.keymap.set({"n", "v"}, "<leader>y", [["+y]])
vim.keymap.set({"n", "v"}, "<leader>d", [["_d]])
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader><leader>", function()
    vim.cmd("so")
end)

vim.keymap.set("i", "kj", "<Esc>")

vim.keymap.set("x", "<leader>p", [["_dP]])
```

my guess is that is has something to do with my leader being `;` and `p` being close to each other on a US layout QWERTY keyboard. But this seams like something useful for the future that I would like to know what I am doing

Comment: I'm afraid we need more clues about what is exactly happens to you. What is the initial situation, what is the final situation and what key could have been hit :-/